# Найти View внутри неотображенного фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-edittext

Пишу приложение c вкладками на главном экране. При нажатии на главную кнопку мне надо получить данные из нескольких `EditText` внутри фрагментов, которые вводил пользователь.
Для инициализации `EditText` использую этот код:

```
private EditText editText;
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    return view;
}
public MyValues getValues() {
    final MyValues val = new MyValues();
    //doWork
    val.someTxt = editText.getText()
    return val;
}
```

Когда метод `getValues` вызывается из другого класса, я получаю - `NullPointerException` на строке:

`val.someTxt = editText.getText()`.

Из [документации андроид](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

> [onCreateView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle))
>   Система вызывает этот метод при первом отображении пользовательского интерфейса фрагмента на дисплее. Для прорисовки пользовательского интерфейса фрагмента следует возвратить из этого метода объект View, который является корневым в макете фрагмента. Если фрагмент не имеет пользовательского интерфейса, можно возвратить null.

Если я правильно понял, метод `onCreateView` не выполняется, если пользователь не открывал данную вкладку и тогда переменная `editText` не инициализируется!

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли. И вы никак не сможете достать этот edittext потому, что его попросту не существует. А раз он не существует, то и текст в нем равен null. Вы можете считать его равным null, или пустой строке, если он еще не инициализирован.

Comment: @metalurgus,  вопрос в том, как найти View из неотображенного фрагмента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MainActivity я написал:

```
private static Context cntxt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cntxt = this;

    //my logic
}
```

В коде фрагмента:

```
private EditText editText;
private boolean flag = false;
private View v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!flag) {
        flag = true;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }
    return v;
}
public MyValues getValues() {
    final MyValues val = new MyValues();
    if (!flag) {
         flag = true;
         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.cntxt);
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, null, false);
         edtText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }
    val.someTxt = editText.getText()
    return val;
}
```